# Android Toolbar home as up indicator material design click effect not shown

Tags: android, toolbar, material-design

I'm working on an Android app with some Material Design features. Currently I'm trying to fix the toolbar, but I have one problem, namely: When I press the home as up arrow to go back to the parent activity, it brings me back to the parent activity but doesn't show a ripple effect (so you see that it is clicked..)

The only thing I do to set the home as up arrow is:

this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

inside my activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug, it was the color of the toolbar. I chose a very dark green color and therefore the click/riffle effect was not visible. Changing the color to something bright fixed the problem for me..